# How do you change iBooks UI format for graphic novel?

Tags: adobe-indesign, epub, ibooks-author

I'm working on a digital graphic novel, moving from InDesign CS6 to iBooks and Kindle. Every page is a giant image, and I can't figure out how to get it to be in the same style as a graphic novel that I purchased.

Example images: [http://imgur.com/a/XfYTt](https://imgur.com/a/XfYTt)

Priorities: Pinch and zoom, largest images possible on page (removing of current margins) 
The goal is to make the book once in InDesign and then publish once while avoiding iBooks Author. If this isn't possible to achieve the format shown in the above link, that's fine.

Comment: since your book shows a top menu and a "page ruler" along the bottom and theirs does not, I must presume there is a "full-page" or "full screen mode" which they have enabled by default. One way to examine how they did it is to make a copy of the file, rename it to zip and unzip it. Examine the code. epub is xhtml and css 2.0 format for the most part.

Answer (score 3):

You will have to open the `.epub` and hard code it to achieve the result you are after.  However, Apple and Amazon will not allow your ebook to pass their validation because your book is completely picture based.  Their policy requires all text to be searchable and not image related.  You may also risk layout issues in regards to portrait and landscape unless you are trying to create a fixed `.epub`.

Comment: Hmm, okay. In that imgur link though, I bought that book off of the iBooks Store and none of the text seems to be highlightable. Do you know how they would have gotten around it?  Thanks so much for the comment, I appreciate the help.

Comment: there is a difference between `searchable` and `highlightable`.  I would have to see the book to figure out what was done.

Comment: @ahainen Most likely the graphics are placed into the file, then text added to the bubbles. It's doubtful that the text was part of the overall illustration.

Comment: Hey, so I'm not sure if the Wright Bros comic had text that was added after or just part of the image. I know for the one I'm editing, it's all lettered and part of one image, so unless I have invisible divs with the same text content, it's just going to be text as an image.

Also, I'm using Lynda.com and Fixed Layout epubs ended up being what I was looking for. When we submit to Amazon and iTunes, I'll post back here on any issues I run into (given that I will have to be editing the code and revalidating)  Thank you for your comments though, I really appreciate it!

Comment: So, the graphic novel we had wasn't 100% pictures, there were some text pages. So, the epub was validated and we were able to submit. But Fixed Layout ePubs were what I needed. We ended up trying CircularFlo and Aquafadas Publishing tools to achieve it. Thanks everyone!